# Informix. ODBC. C#. Execute stored procedure and sql statement in one request

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, odbc, informix

We have:
- Informix 11.5 connection via ODBC driver.
- .Net service witch executes queries via ODBC
- StoredProcedure that does queries and insert result into TEMP table. We don't have permissions to edit or create SP in db.

We need
Execute stored procedure and get data from temp table.

Here is a Stored Procedure SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "informix".sp_shp_hist(Ship_dt_fr VARCHAR(50),Ship_dt_to VARCHAR(50))
    SELECT blh_shp_dt AS ShipDate, 
        blh_cus_no AS Customer, 
        ...
    WHERE  blh_shp_dt between Ship_dt_fr and Ship_dt_to 
    into temp temp_sah;

    SELECT * 
    from  temp_sah inner join injitd_rec
    ON (sat_ref_itm = itd_ref_itm) 
    AND (sat_ref_no = itd_ref_no) 
    AND (sat_ref_pfx = itd_ref_pfx) 
    AND (sat_ssn_brh = itd_ssn_brh) 
    into temp temp_sah1;

    SELECT * from   temp_sah1 left outer join inatag_rec
        ON (itd_whs1 = tag_whs1) 
        ...
        AND (tag_ga = itd_ga) into temp temp_sah2;

    SELECT 
        ShipDate, 
        ... 
    AND (itd_ga = prd_ga) into temp temp_sah21;

    SELECT ... into temp temp_sah3;

    drop table temp_sah;
    drop table temp_sah1;
    drop table temp_sah2;
    drop table temp_sah21;

end procedure;
```

I found out the query that works in RazorSql when hit 'Execute SQL'

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_shp_hist(TO_CHAR(TODAY-3,"%Y%m%d" ), TO_CHAR(TODAY-1,"%Y%m%d" ));

select * from temp_sah3
where customer = 1;
```

when we try execute this sql via our service we got the result:

> ERROR [42S02] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]The specified
>   table (temp_sah3) is not in the database.

How to make the informix execute all sql statements one-by-one? or any other ideas?

Comment: Temporary tables are associated with a session. Your service seems to be using different sessions to execute each of the 2 statements, so the 2nd statement fails because the temporary table does not exist in the session where it is being executed. In razor SQL you are executing all the statements in the same session, so the temporary table is visible to the second statement.

Comment: I think the problem is that Informix prepares both statements and then executes them, but when it prepares the second (SELECT) statement, the table `temp_sah3` doesn't exist because the stored procedure hasn't been run to create it.  You'll need to separate the two statements into separate operations for it to work with Informix.